# Adding border-radius to a map

Tags: maps, openlayers, css

I have a website running on a mapping platform called Ushahidi. The default template is quite boxy so I was fiddling with the CSS and rounding everything off using border-radius.

It has helped with other elements but the map is such a square it won't ease up!

It might be that it's not possible, wondered if anyone here had any experience of this. The html using inspect element and view source are different. Not sure what this means exactly but guessing that the html is pulled in by the map provider?

Here is the html on view source:

```
<div class="map " id="map"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="mapStatus">
    <div id="mapScale"></div>
    <div id="mapMousePosition"></div>
    <div id="mapProjection"></div>
    <div id="mapOutput"></div>
</div>
```

I've added a screen of inspect element HTML too. Looks like it's using "Open Layers". I've heard of that but don't fully understand whats going on.

Is it possible to round the edges of my map? Here is the site if that helps: http://tinyurl.com/c8djrvr

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `border-radius` to two layers.

**CSS**

```
div.map {
    border: #999 1px solid;
    width: 800px;
    height: 366px;
    position: relative;
    height: 650px;
    border-radius: 25px;      /* ADD THIS */
}

#OpenLayers_Map_11_OpenLayers_ViewPort {
    border-radius: 25px;      /* ADD THIS */
}
```

It works. Use however many pixels you want. I used `25px`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest more general and safer CSS selectors (since ID `#OpenLayers_Map_11_OpenLayers_ViewPort` is generated by OpenLayers and it's value is unpredictable; and OL 2.12 and older produce ID's, that contain dot and are therefore unsuitable for CSS selectors):

```
.olMap, .olMapViewport {
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```